# Select product image using SQL in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, sql

In Magento 2, how can I get the product image using only MySQL queries? For example, /c/t/ct0126black.jpg. All of my products are configurable products so they have different images for different colours.

Comment: u can see Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image.php.

Comment: I meant that I need to know how to do this using MySQL queries. It's for a script that I'm writing outside of Magento's framework.

Comment: @LiamMcArthur Just a note. I understand you are doing this outside of Magento but my recommendation would be to create a frontend controller to handle the query instead of a standalone script. The controller retrieves the images etc in a standard Magento collection. You would query the controller from your outside script, you get much tighter security in this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the below query.

```
select gal.value from catalog_product_entity as ent
left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value as val on (ent.row_id= val.row_id)
left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery as gal on (val.value_id = gal.value_id)
where ent.type_id='configurable';
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all configurable products with their pathes to images

```
select * from catalog_product_entity ent
left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value val on (val.entity_id=ent.entity_id)
left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery gal on (gal.value_id=val.value_id)
where ent.type_id='configurable';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for Magento 2

```
SELECT e.entity_id AS 'id',
       e.sku AS 'sku',
       v2.value AS 'image',
       v3.value AS 'thumbnail',
       v4.value AS 'small image',
       mg.value AS 'media_gallery'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.row_id
AND v2.store_id = 0
AND v2.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'image'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v3 ON e.entity_id = v3.row_id
AND v3.store_id = 0
AND v3.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'thumbnail'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v4 ON e.entity_id = v4.row_id
AND v4.store_id = 0
AND v4.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'small_image'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT m1.value_id AS m1_value_id, GROUP_CONCAT(m2.value) AS VALUE, m2.value_id AS m2_value_id, m1.row_id AS m1_row_id
   FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value m1
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery m2 ON m2.value_id = m1.value_id
   AND m2.attribute_id =
     (SELECT attribute_id
      FROM eav_attribute
      WHERE attribute_code = 'media_gallery'
        AND entity_type_id =
          (SELECT entity_type_id
           FROM eav_entity_type
           WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
   GROUP BY m1.row_id) mg ON e.entity_id = m1_row_id
WHERE e.sku IN
(
"sku1",
"sku2",
"sku3"
);
```